# How do I synthetically slow page load times?

Tags: javascript, html, web, metrics

I would like to be able to synthetically add a fixed interval to page load times. This is the exact opposite of what most everyone else wants. I want to be able to say "Add an $n second delay to the loading of this page."

What can I use to achieve this result? Can this be done in javascript? The system I want to do this to uses some pretty aggressive output caching I don't have complete control over.

Goal: measure effects of page load speed on other key metrics so I can determine the value of improving that metric.

Comment: Client-side Javascript isn't going to execute until at least some portion of the page has loaded, so I'm assuming that's out.  What's your system developed in?  Any dynamically generated page can have simple waits put into the server side code to simply make them stall for a second or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a large file download at the top of the page body (huge js file, or large jpeg that's hidden).

Also you could just use a timer in javascript and only show the contents of the body once the timer expires.

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to load the page at a set interval.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a synchronous ajax request to your server and then sleep inside your php script.